# How to restrict access to an iframe called by TYPO3 webpage?

Tags: apache, iframe, typo3-7.6.x

I have TYPO3 7.6.20 with php 7.1 and apache 2.4 on WINDOWS.

Moreover I have a webpage in the site where a php page via an iframe is called by the lp_iframe extenion. It works fine, but now I woulde like to restrict access to this iframe by IP address. Can anyone here tell how it is done? I know that on apache I can restrict page access by allowed/deny directive but as the TYPO3 webpage calles the iframe the calling host is always localhost.

Thanks in advance. Walter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must consider something new.
If you embedd an iframe in your webpage, the content of the iframe is not called from your server, but the browser of your website visitor.

Maybe you meant a restriction from which domains the iframe can be embedded. That has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629414/how-to-restrict-who-can-iframe-embed-my-web-app).